# Recebendo paramento na View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá! Estou tentando receber um parâmetro de filtro em minha view com o seguinte código no `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Cadastro(int? idParente)
    {
        var tab_Documentos_Parente = db.Tab_Documentos_Parente.Where(campo => campo.Id_Parente == idParente).Include(t => t.Tab_Documentos_Cadastrais_Par).Include(t => t.Tab_Parente);
        return View(tab_Documentos_Parente.ToList());
    }
```

Mas quando informo a url: *http://localhost:53316/Documentos_Parente/Cadastro/1*
Simplesmente não executa o filtro. Fazendo um `Debug`no `Controller` vejo que meu parâmetro está sempre sendo recebido como `null`.

**Não basta apenas informar .../1 ao final na URL?**
Como então posso enviar o id que quero filtrar?

o modelo é o seguinte:

```
public partial class Tab_Documentos_Parente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome do Parente")]
    public int Id_Parente { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição do Documento")]
    public Nullable<int> Id_Documento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Documento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public byte[] Documento { get; set; }

    public virtual Tab_Documentos_Cadastrais_Par Tab_Documentos_Cadastrais_Par { get; set; }
    public virtual Tab_Parente Tab_Parente { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Alam, você configurou a rota para que ela entenda que o `/1` é um parametro?

Comment: Tenta com a url ` http://localhost:53316/Documentos_Parente/Cadastro?idParente=1 ` se funcionar é porque você não configurou a rota corretamente.

Comment: Tem razão @LeonardoBonetti a url que você sugeriu funcionou. Mas como funciona com as Views de Edit e Delete geradas pelo Scaffold, imaginei que seria apena seguir o mesmo modelo. Onde configuro essa rota?

Comment: vou criar uma resposta FODA, me aguarde.

Comment: Kkkkk! Aguardando de boa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não sei toda a hierarquia do seu projeto vou dar um exemplo do meu projeto.

Eu tenho um HomeController com a view Image(é uma view de resultado de imagem):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Image(string id)
    {
        //Processa id
        return View(id);

    }
}
```

Quando eu fosse chamar essa view passando o `id` eu teria que requisitar isso: `http://localhost:53316/Home/Image?id=1` porém contudo todavia, como já diria aquele sábio chamado Google, nada melhor que uma URL amigável.

A url amigável ficaria assim: `http://localhost:53316/Home/Image/1` Mas  como fazer isso? Você precisa MAPEAR uma nova [rota(Route)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Para configurar uma nova rota, você deve editar o arquivo `RouteConfig.cs` na pasta **App_Start** da raiz do seu projeto. Como rota padrão você já tem:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Você irá criar uma nova rota, não exclua a rota padrão(Pelo amor que você tem no seu projeto), a nova rota ficaria assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "Image/{produtoid}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Image" },
            new { produtoid = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

[Nesse link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd460520(v=vs.118).aspx) você pode ver o overload que usamos para mapear essa rota.

- `"Home"` - nome da sua rota.
- `"Image/{produtoid}"` - o padrão de url para sua rota.
- `new { controller = "Home", action = "Image" },` - você passa o controller/view que a sua rota irá ser aplicada.
- `new { produtoid = UrlParameter.Optional }` os parametros da url

Agora sim ! você já pode utilizar o padrão da pergunta: http://localhost:53316/Documentos_Parente/Cadastro/1    , se você configurou tudo certinho, com os nomes corretos e etc tudo funcionará. Pelo que eu entendi do pouco código que você inseriu, a rota ficaria assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Documentos_Parente",
        "Cadastro/{parenteid}",
        new { controller = "Documentos_Parente", action = "Cadastro" },
        new { parenteid= UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Eu aprendi a fazer isso no post: [Customizando Rotas](http://www.macoratti.net/15/09/mvc_crotas1.htm)  do site do José Carlos Macoratti(que é um site **MUITO** bom para quem aprende MVC, tem bastante conteúdo e de fácil entendimento. Espero que isso resolva, espero o retorno(comentários) de você ou qualquer outro com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Você realmente fez uma super resposta, clocou até a referencia do msdn.microsoft.com e do site do macoratti... Não ficou nenhuma dúvida. A rota que você sugeriu funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @AlamBique eu que agradeço pela oportunidade de  ajudar.